# Apple TV required switching hardware / mobile WiFi router

Tags: appletv, performance, router

I am considering Apple TV for a trips, but usually the hotels' wifis' connections are separated. I came up with using my Vodafone branded Huawei R201 mobile wifi router for that purpose, but I am not sure if that hardware is powerful enough for sending Full HD video from my iPad/iPod/Mac to Apple TV.

Is there some parameter on wifi routers (I am opened to buy another one), which say "Yes, it WILL work"?

Comment: wouldn't it be much simpler (and cheaper) to buy a HDMI dock adapter?

Comment: Difference is not much noticable. I have iPad 3.gen and iPod touch 4.gen -- 30 pins. I am considering new iPhone -- Lightning. With hdmi cable it's almost same expenses and with Apple TV i don't have to connect the iOS devices for some usage.

Comment: And now i realized it would require also hdmi kit for my Mac, so the "not Apple TV" is even more expensive